# Upgrade to Java 8 breaks jmsQueue definition on Liberty Server

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, jndi, websphere-liberty

I'm working on a project to bring a Java 7 application up to Java 8.  The components are Liberty 8.5.5.9 and IBM MQ 9.  We also have a WebSphere server that provides an RMI connection to some backend servers, but I don't think that's really related to this issue.

On Java 7, the standard configuration for a jmsQueue and jmsActivationSpec work perfectly fine.  When I upgrade to Java 8, all of a sudden, the jmsQueue isn't registering with the JNDI.  The ONLY thing that has been done is the version of Java changed from 7 to 8.  These are both IBM version of Java.

This is my server.xml configuration for my MQ.

```
<variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="${shared.config.dir}/wmq/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
<jmsQueueConnectionFactory connectionManagerRef="Liberty_ConnMgr" id="MyQueueConnectionFactory" jndiName="jms/MyQueueConnectionFactory">
    <properties.wmqJms channel="JAVA.CHANNEL" hostName="localhost" port="1517" queueManager="MY_QMGR" transportType="CLIENT" />
</jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
<jmsConnectionFactory connectionManagerRef="Liberty_ConnMgr" jndiName="jms/QueueConnFactory">
    <properties.wmqJms channel="JAVA.CHANNEL" hostName="localhost" port="1517" queueManager="MY_QMGR" />
</jmsConnectionFactory>
<connectionManager id="Liberty_ConnMgr" maxPoolSize="2"/>
<jmsQueue id="jms/WQ1" jndiName="jms/MYQueueApp">
    <properties.wmqJms baseQueueName="MYQUEUE" baseQueueManagerName="MY_QMGR" />
</jmsQueue>
<jmsActivationSpec id="MyApp/MyMessageBean">
    <properties.wmqJms destinationRef="jms/WQ1" hostName="localhost" messageSelector="TARGET='MAINAPP'" port="1517" queueManager="MY_QMGR" transportType="CLIENT" />
</jmsActivationSpec>
```

Error Message:

```
    [INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA0003: A JNDI naming exception was thrown. See the linked exception for details., error code: MQJCA0003 An attempt to look up a JMS destination in the JNDI namespace failed. Either the namespace cannot be accessed, or a destination with the supplied name is not bound in the namespace.  See the linked exception for details of the failure. Check that the JNDI namespace is available, that a destination with the correct name is bound in the JNDI namespace, and that the value of the property called destination is correctly defined. com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService 534" at ffdc_22.02.03_11.33.25.0.log
[ERROR   ] J2CA8802E: The message endpoint activation failed for resource adapter wmqJms due to exception: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA0003: A JNDI naming exception was thrown. See the linked exception for details., error code: MQJCA0003 An attempt to look up a JMS destination in the JNDI namespace failed. Either the namespace cannot be accessed, or a destination with the supplied name is not bound in the namespace.  See the linked exception for details of the failure. Check that the JNDI namespace is available, that a destination with the correct name is bound in the JNDI namespace, and that the value of the property called destination is correctly defined.
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:169)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:135)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.DestinationBuilder.createDestination(DestinationBuilder.java:238)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.startDelivery(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:343)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.<init>(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:236)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:556)
        at com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService.activateEndpoint(EndpointActivationService.java:525)
        at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms/WQ1
        at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.ContextNode.lookup(ContextNode.java:218)
        at [internal classes]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.DestinationBuilder.createDestination(DestinationBuilder.java:190)
        ... 5 more
.
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA0003: A JNDI naming exception was thrown. See the linked exception for details., error code: MQJCA0003 An attempt to look up a JMS destination in the JNDI namespace failed. Either the namespace cannot be accessed, or a destination with the supplied name is not bound in the namespace.  See the linked exception for details of the failure. Check that the JNDI namespace is available, that a destination with the correct name is bound in the JNDI namespace, and that the value of the property called destination is correctly defined. com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.mdb.internal.MessageEndpointFactoryImpl 119" at ffdc_22.02.03_11.33.26.0.log
```

Comment: You need to look at the log from the start maybe there will be some additional info there as this just complains about missing JNDI name.

Comment: Thanks Gas. I've been over the logs from the start many times, this is the first entry related to the problem. No other warnings or other clues.